# .htaccess mod_rewrite pretty URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to get my URLs from this:

```
www.exmple.com/test.php?type=abc&id=12345
to
www.exmple.com/rrr/abc
```

is it possible... ?
thanks

Comment: ¿Do you want `www.exmple.com/test.php?type=abc&id=12345` to remain the resource address or it will be at the "pretty" url?

Comment: -1: A simple Google search would have answered your question: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Comment: i want Q.string after the url will be rrr and then type.... rrr/type

Comment: Then folder `/rrr/type` must exist with an index.php file to process the request, unless the original resource address is kept. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: @Felipe Alameda A you means i must be define all prety url in index.php ?

Comment: No. I did not mean that.

Comment: how can i change this to... www.exmple.com/any-string..? @Felipe Alameda A

Answer (score 0):

yes.possible

To solve this issue simply add the following to your htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.html HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

More resources [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)